Use of "Near no money"
I recently came across the expression "near no money" and I'm trying to understand a little more about it, how it can be used, etc. Is this a type of expression that could be used in a sentence like this?
How much am I making working for my uncle? Well, to be honest, near no money, but I'm getting a lot of experience.

It might make more sense if it were a number, like "How much? Near 100." And here "no money" is an amount.

it means almost no money  ... not much money may be more common

A search in Google Books got me these three hits just from the first page:
The Putter: Not A Sports Story
Murder on a Small Island - Page viii
Lost Youth Volume 2: London - Volume 2 - Page 226
The OP’s suggested use hence seems fine.  The words take their ordinary meanings.

Thank you, Seowjooheng. In fact, I had done a lot of research and even found two of the examples you mentioned, and as I do whenever I discover a new expression, I tried to create some sentences using it for better memorization. What I wasn't sure was that this expression would be suitable in the sense of the phrase I created, that is, with the sense of income or payment for work, or something similar.

@Itamar I wouldn't say that you have to use this pattern yourself; in this context, salary, you could use "nearly" instead.
